# How to choose an antenna for an FM transmitter?

Tags: antenna, frequency, modulation, telecommunications

Ok guys I can't understand something.

Say that I have this circuit:

[image]

Assuming that I apply at the antenna 5V, how can I calculate how much power I will trasmit?

I found on internet that the current that will flow on the antenna radiation resistance, but if for example I go on ebay for try to find antenna no one quote the antenna radiation resistance, so how can I choose my antenna?

Moreover I want to know what  capacitor C1 and C2 do in this circuit.

Comment: The antenna will only radiate when an AC voltage is applied. So 5V DC will not work. The circuit generates such an AC voltage with some base frequency and some additional frequency deviation providedby MIC1.

Comment: You're **overthinking this**. 1) you should not apply 5 V to the antenna connection but at the top of L1 otherwise this circuit isn't going to work. 2) This is an **extremely simple** circuit, how much power it transmits will depend on many factors including the antenna. If you worry about "transmitted power" then you're not grasping the fact that this circuit is too simple to talk about that. 3) usually the antenna is just a piece of wire like 30 cm long. Buying an "antenna" for this crappy circuit is a waste of money.

Comment: The circuit is a variation of a Colpitts oscillator, read more here: https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/comms-lab-colpitts-osc  But again: this isn't a serious circuit, it is a "toy" circuit. Also note that using it might be **illegal** in your country as most of these transmit in the FM radio band which is usually **prohibited**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie in any case, if I buy an antenna which factor I have to look, that will let assimilate the antenna as resistor, so I can easily calculate the Transmitted Power?

Comment: Antennas aren't "assimilated as a resistor", antennas have an **impedance**. But that's irrelevant here as this circuit is too simple, it does not have a proper output impedance that you can match to an antenna. You have two options: 1) You use a piece of wire (30 cm) as the antenna **or** 2) you **study** RF circuits to better understand what I'm trying to explain above. Then you'll learn that what you insist on doing now (improving the antenna) is pointless and "silly".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Let's say that I have another circuit, this circuit is a 100W Well done trasmitter, how can I calculate the power that the antenna transmitt? [I know that the impedance must be addapted for avoid leaks]

Comment: I think that's a different question and one to be asked after youve done some more research and study.